# XJC [ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//*[local-name()='schema']" results in empty target node

Tags: java, xpath, jaxb, wsdl, xjc

I am new to XJC. I'm attempting to consume a WSDL and generate binding classes with the XJC command and I got the following error:

```
C:\jaxb>xjc -verbose -b c:\jaxb\bindings-wsdl.xjb -wsdl c:\jaxb\BioMetScrnSvc.wsdl
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//*[local-name()='schema']" results in empty target node
line 8 of file:/C:/jaxb/bindings-wsdl.xjb

Failed to parse a schema.
```

My binding file is as follows:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" 
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:impl="http://www.openuri.org/" 
xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:intf="http://www.openuri.org/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <jaxb:bindings node="//*[local-name()='schema']">
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/> 
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The WSDL provided to me is something as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.openuri.org/"
 xmlns:impl="http://www.openuri.org/"
 xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"    
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   
xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:intf="http://www.openuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.openuri.org/" 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 ...
```

From all the suggestions I have read from this site, I have included the necessary namespaces into the binding file to no avail. I have tested the Xpath and it is correct.

If I don't have a binding file, a JAXBElement is generated instead of a String. Understood it is  because of minOccurs and nillable occurring together.

Regards, 
Wes

Comment: As your are trying to consume a WSDL, is there any reason that you're not using [wsimport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html)?

Comment: Hi I have used wsimport as well; and I got the same result.

Comment: [ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//*[local-name()='schema']" results in empty target
 node
  line 8 of file:/C:/jaxb/bindings-wsdl.xjb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not make bindings work with `node`. This might be a bug in XJC, I'll check/report to Oracle.

But SCD bindings do work! So here's a solution for you. Make a file namely "wsdl.xjb" and put following code in it. And place it on the same folder (for simplicity OR you can place anywhere then you will need to mention its path) where you have your example.wsdl file.

```
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="2.0">

    <jaxb:bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://www.openuri.org/">
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

You'll need to include a `-extension` command switch and your final command will look like this:

```
xjc -extension -verbose -wsdl example.wsdl -b wsdl.xjb
```

Comment: Hi just to clarify, based on my XSD above it should be:

<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.0">

    <jaxb:bindings scd="x-schema::tns" xmlns:tns="http://www.openuri.org/">
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>

Comment: @WesOng Correct. I have update the code to use your URI.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but I am still facing some problems.

When I use the binding file on a XSD it works, i.e. a String is created rather than a JAXBElement. However if I run it vs a WSDL I still get the JAXBElement.

Comment: @WesOng This is a different question, please close this one and create another one.